# Re-Posting $_POST arrays

Tags: php, arrays, post, recursion

I have a script that previews entered data prior to user acceptance of same, it requires the form data to be re-posted so it can be finally processed, some of the data is in array form & I looked for an efficient function to perform that which I couldn't find, so I have created this:

```
    function repost_array ($value, $key, $mkey) {
            echo draw_hidden_field($mkey.'[' . $key . ']', htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($value)));
    }   
    /* Re-Post all POST'ed variables */
    reset($_POST);
    while (list($key, $value) = each($_POST)) if (!is_array($_POST[$key])) echo draw_hidden_field($key, htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($value)));
    reset($_POST);
     while (list($key, $value) = each($_POST)) if (is_array($_POST[$key]))  array_walk_recursive($_POST[$key], 'repost_array', $key);
```

Please advise if there is a better way or if I have missed anything (I`ve not tested how deep the recursive function will work).

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do. You are receiving a post, but then want the user to post it again why?

Comment: Don't require the user to re-post it. Save it in a session variable, and when they confirm just use the session variable.

Comment: Or save in in a database table with a flag like isProcessed

Comment: The user is modifying their content, the preview gives them the chance to see the new content before confirming the update, they also have the option of returning to edit, so their are 2 paths from here, back to edit or write to dBase.

Comment: What would be the advantage of using $_SESSION over $_POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repost the values, though I recommend using other alternatives like the `$_SESSION` super global, something similar to:

```
<?php
session_start();//session start has to be at the very top of your page!
?>

<!-- ... your html code  -->

<?php 

// ... your php code...

$_SESSION['key'] = $_POST['key'];
```

And from there, you can use `$_SESSION['key']` anywhere in your code to obtain the stored value (as long as the session is active, which depending on your configurations is usually around 30 minutes but can be made to be longer, like 7 days for instance)

Comment: The current input code looks for matching $_POST vars to fill the fields if returning from preview or an entry error is flagged, so would simply doing $_SESSION['key'] = $_POST then if back to edit restoring $_POST vars with $_POST = $_SESSION['key'] be a valid method, or would that add security issues?

Comment: using the method would add one layer of security for sure. Imagiine for instance a `hacker` makes a webpage that when someone enters, redirects to your page but sends information via the `POST` method, which could include XSS scripts or other malicious content. You would be preventing that sort of attack for one. You should not limit yourself to just using `$_SESSION`, you should also filter out any special characters obtained from user input. `SUMMARY`, yes it would be a valid method and yes it adds a layer of security for the above reason for instance.